# Why is it telling me the sum of 5 numbers is 250 when it's 15?

Tags: c#, char

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
class Solution
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int value=0;
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        string s = Console.ReadLine();

        for(int i = 0;i<=s.Length-1;i++){
            if(s[i]!=0){
                value+=s[i];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
            else{value=0;}
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm stupid af. The code is to take `5` numbers from a string and add them up. If it finds a `0` then it sets the value back to `0` and caries on adding up again. But it's telling me the value of `12345` is **250**

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which will help you write better code.

Comment: I would expect the outcome to be 255. Is that correct?

Comment: Those chars have an Unicode value. You're summing Unicode codepoints. It's not clear what `n` is used for. This: `i <= s.Length - 1` can be *refactored*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s[i]` is not giving you a number, it's giving you a character. `+=` will add up the ASCII (or Unicode) value of that character. See it here:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)'1');
```

That way you'll get 49 + 50 + 51 + 52 + 53, which is 255.

Use `int.Parse()` to convert a string to a number:

```
value+=int.Parse(""+s[i]);
```

In programs you'll also see this a lot:

```
value+=s[i] - '0';
```

That also works because the character 0 is in front of character 1, so 49 - 48 = 1.

The second bug in your program is

```
if(s[i]!=0){
```

For the same reason (character versus number) that should read

```
if(s[i]!='0'){
```

`n` seems unused. You can remove that line.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you actully sum `char`s, not `int`s:

```
  value+=s[i]; // since s is string, s[i] is of type char
```

So you have

```
'1' + '2' + '3' + '4' + '5' == // chars
 49 + 50 + 51 + 52 + 53 ==     // corresponding ASCII codes
 255
```

You should sum `int`s; in order to convert from `'0'` to `0` you can just subtract `0`:

```
 string s = Console.ReadLine();

 for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i) {
   if (s[i] >= '1' && s[i] <= '9') { // 1..9 numbers only 
     value += s[i] - '0'; // <- Note - '0'

     Console.WriteLine(value);
   }
   else 
     value = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are adding chars to int:

- s[i] is not a int, is a char
- the value of the char '1' as a numeric value that can be added to an int. That value is not 1 but 48.
- You think you are doing 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 but you are doing '1' + '2' + '3' + '4' + '5' = 48 + 49 + 50 + 51 + 52 = 250.

you have to do

```
 value+=int.Parse(""+s[i]);
```

to achieve what you want